# Integrable distribution iff locally constant (manifolds)

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

In order to prove the Frobenius Theorem for smooth manifold as my Professor did in class, I want to prove that the definition of integrable distribution and locally constant distribution coincide.

**Definition 0** A $k$-distribution $D$ on smooth $n$-manifold $M$ is a $k$-subbundle of his tangent bundle $TM$ * 
(that is, for every $p\in M$ $D(p)$ is a $k$-affine subspace of $T_pM$ (and the assignement is smooth in $p$) ).

**Definition 1** A k-distribution on M is **integrable** if it is induced by a foliation on M, that is, if there exists a partition $\mathcal{F}$ of $M$ in $k$-injectively immersed submanifolds (called leafs) such that for every $p\in M$ there exists a chart $\phi: U(p) \to \mathbb{R}^n= \mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$ that sends every leaf into an union of $k$-horizontal affine subspaces.

**Definition 2** A k-distribution on $M$ is locally constant if for every $p \in M$ there exists a chart $\phi: U(p) \to  \mathbb{R}^n= \mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k} $ that sends $D$ into a constant $k$-distribution of $ \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to prove that:

**Proposition** $D$ is integrable if and only if it is locally constant.

I can prove that if $D$ is integrable, than it is locally constant (just take the foliation that induces $D$ and the charts given by hypothesis, and then use the fact that $T_x(\mathbb{R}^k\times \{q\})= \mathbb{R}^k\times \{0\}$ canonically). However, I don't see how to prove the other implication.
I know that giving a foliation on a manifold is equivalent to giving a smooth atlas where the transition maps (seen as maps from and to open subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^k\times  \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$) send points of the same height to point of the same height, and I wanted to use it, but I cannot see how.

Any help would be *really* appreciated!

Comment: Have you read the standard proofs of how you take the maximal integral submanifolds? That give you the leaves of the foliation. This is in all the standard textbooks.

Comment: Actually I have been studying from my professors' notes, and in there the proof is omitted (maybe it should be obvious but I don't see it). Could you please suggest me a book where I can find what you said? Thanks :)

Comment: Any standard book on differentiable manifolds. Classics are Warner, Spivak Volume I, Boothby, and there's a popular newer book by John Lee.